# How to pass objects into angular.js directives? Interpolated argument appears to be serialised

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I'm trying to pass a JavaScript object into an angular directive. I'm invoking it like this:

```
<thing-badge thing="{{thing}}"></thing>
```

The directive looks something like this:

```
directives.directive('thingBadge', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        controller: function($scope) {
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, $scope) {

          attrs.$observe('thing', function(thing) {
              console.log(thing);
          }
        }
     }
}
```

Let's say that thing is a JS object: `{'an': "object'}`. I want to get the value of this object in my directive. Instead I'm getting a serialisation of the object: `'{"an": "object"}'` of type string.

If I pass in a `number` (e.g. `<thing-badge thing="{{thing.id}}"></thing>`) I also get a string, e.g. `"0"`.

How do I pass an actual object in there?

Answer (score 2):

you need to add an isolate scope:

```
directives.directive('thingBadge', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            thing: '='
        },
        controller: function($scope) {
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, $scope) {

          attrs.$observe('thing', function(thing) {
              console.log(thing);
          }
        }
     }
}
```

and you shouldn't need the curly brace notation in the element:

```
<thing-badge thing="thing"></thing-badge>
```

Comment: The answer was invalid, and @Joe your edit helps, but it's was still invalid.

Comment: Hi @Connor I've not yet tried this out. Could you say why it's not valid?

Comment: @Joe it is now, it wasn't because the name in the `scope: {}` and in the `$observer` and the attribute should all be the same.

Comment: Cheers for that. Easily spotted and fixed (although I missed it first time). I thought you meant there was something more serious wrong.